# Let S be the set of all reals where every other decimal place, starting with the first one, contains a 1.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

(so, for instance, S contains 23.101816191... but not 0.123419...)
(a) Show that the cardinality of positive integers is less than or equal to the cardinality of the set S
(b) Is the cardinality of set S equal to the cardinality of the real numbers?

For (a) I have been playing around with the concept that the cardinality of X is less than or equal to the cardinality of Y if there is an injection from X to Y
For (b) I know the answer is no because the reals are uncountable, but I'm not sure how to explain this/prove this.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: For (b), how do you know $S$ is countable?  It wouldn't seem to be, if (a) is true.

Comment: Does "positive numbers" mean "positive integers" or "positive real numbers"? Ross Millikan seems to assume the former in his answer..

Comment: @Ross: You're reading this the other way around. Or that you're understanding "positive numbers" as integers and not "real numbers". (As the context here is the reals, I suppose that "numbers" refer to real numbers, not just integers.)

Comment: @RossMillikan But if "positive numbers" means positive real numbers, then the cardinality of $S$ cannot be countable.  If "positive numbers" simply means $\mathbb{N}$, then I agree that it could be countable.  But it would appear that the former is the intended meaning, from context.

Comment: @fgp positive integers.. sorry!

Comment: @Sally Fair enough.  That changes things entirely.  It would seem that the stronger statement may also be true, by simply reworking the proof for positive integers using decimal approximations certain numbers of digits, or by simply using the injection you construct for (b) and the fact that the cardinality of (0,1) is the cardinality of the real numbers.

Comment: @NicholasStull if I prove (a), have I proved that S is uncountable? And does that, in turn, prove (b)?

Comment: @Sally No.  If you prove (a) as you currently stated (i.e., that the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$ is less than or equal to the cardinality of $S$), all you have proven is that the cardinality of $S$ is at least countable.  Proving part (b) will actually involve constructing the injection of $(0,1)$ into $S$ using the idea in Ross Millikan's answer below, which will in turn prove that the cardinality of $S$ is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Sally My comment in response to yours was alluding to the thought that it may very well be possible to prove that the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is less than or equal to the cardinality of $S$, but without sitting down and making sure the construction of the injection as in Ross Millikan's answer carries through, I can't be certain.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct with your idea for a.  Can you find an explicit injection from $\Bbb N$ into $S$?  Hint:  $345 \to 0.1314151\overline{01}$ For b, you are not correct that $S$ is countable.  Can you find an injection from $(0,1)$ into $S$ using the same idea?  As all the members of $S$ are reals, that shows that $S$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$

Comment: A somewhat simpler way to embedd $\mathbb{N}$ into $S$ is to simply use $n \mapsto n + 0.10101.\ldots$.

Comment: So @fgp f(n)=n+.10101? And then I would need to prove this function is an injection? But also prove that the function is not a surjection? Or is this last step not necessary?

Comment: You only need an injection to prove the cardinality is less than or equal.  fgp's version is $n \to n+\frac{10}{99}$ which is clearly an injection.